# How to properly load .properties on distributable jar file?

Tags: java, swing, jar, filereader

I am trying to load a **.properties** file(s) into my distributable jar file. This is what I did so far:

In my **config.properties** file, I defined this properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password =
```

and on my class **DBManager**, I have this methods:

```
//Default Constructor
public DBManagerImpl(){
    JDBC_DRIVER = getResource().getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    }...
}

//Getting properties file
private Properties getResource(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);
    } ...
    return prop;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        DATABASE_URL = getResource().getProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/defaultdb");
        username = getResource().getProperty("jdbc.username", "root");
        password = getResource().getProperty("jdbc.password", "");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, username, password);
    } ...
    return connection;
}
```

Like wise, I also have another file, **book.csv**, which contains list of book to be loaded on my table.

My problem now is that upon upon generating a jar file, if I change my definitions on **config.properties** or modify my **book.csv** and run my distributable file it does not render changes.

Hope someone can point out solution.

**Any help is very much appreciated**

Comment: *"if I change my definitions on config.properties or modify my book.csv and run my distributable file it does not render changes."* DYM the Jar is being rebuilt? By "I" DYM you the developer or you the end user?

Comment: It does not rebuilt. And yeah, I am referring to the end user. The purpose in creating the config is to dynamically change the database. I mean instead of localhost, the end user can change another database location.